# android tabs not working

Tags: java, android, tabs, listener

I was following a tutorial about tabs in android and did everything exactly like in the video. There's a bunch of code, however i'm getting an error on one of the lines tab1.setTabListener(new ActionBar.TabListener(fragment1)); it says 'TabListener' is abstract; cannot be instantiated. How do I fix this?

Here's the full code of the activity which has the error inside of it:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ProjectCreateScreen extends ActionBarActivity {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondary_layout1);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.AwesomeBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ActionBar.Tab tab1, tab2, tab3;

    // Fragments that will load when the tabs are clicked
    Fragment fragment1 = new TabFragment1();
    Fragment fragment2 = new TabFragment2();
    Fragment fragment3 = new TabFragment3();

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    // Set the current navigation mode to tabs
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Add titles to tabs
    tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1");
    tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2");
    tab3 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab3");

    // Set tab listeners which provide callbacks for tab events
    // A callback informs another class when an action occurs
    tab1.setTabListener(new ActionBar.TabListener(fragment1));
    tab2.setTabListener(new ActionBar.TabListener(fragment2));
    tab3.setTabListener(new ActionBar.TabListener(fragment3));

    // Adds tabs to the actionbar
    actionBar.addTab(tab1);
    actionBar.addTab(tab2);
    actionBar.addTab(tab3);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a class that implements TabListener interface

```
protected class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener{
    private Fragment fragment;

    public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment){
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft){
        ft.add(R.id.layout2, fragment, null);
    }
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }
}
```

and then set the tabListener

```
tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragment1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that implements `ActionBar.TabListener` and call that class in `setTabListener`.

There are two ways to go about this:

1. Create a new class that implements `ActionBar.TabListener`. For example:

   ```
   protected class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {  
       private Fragment fragment;

       public MyTabListener(Fragment fragment){
           this.fragment = fragment;
       }
       public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft){
           ft.add(R.id.layout, fragment, null);
       }
       public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
       }
       public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
           ft.remove(fragment);
       }
   }
   ```

   Then set the `TabListener`:

   ```
   tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragment1));
   ```
2. Have your `MainActivity` implement `ActionBar.TabListener` and override the methods required. For example:

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener { 

       @Override
       public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
           // When the given tab is selected, show the tab contents in the
           // container view.
           Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
           getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
       }

       @Override
       public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
       }

       @Override
       public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
       }
   }
   ```